# Amplify V6 social provider sign in with react native

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, expo, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I upgraded to aws amplify v6 because there was a bug with sign-out on iOS (it pops up sign-in window for some reason). Everything works fine except the social provider sign in. I have google, apple and facebook sign in that I invoke like this:

```js
import { signInWithRedirect } from 'aws-amplify/auth';
await signInWithRedirect({
    provider: 'Apple',
});
```

This is supposed to redirect the user to the oauth screen, where I try to access the user data:

```js
import { getCurrentUser } from 'aws-amplify/auth';
const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();
```

It worked for version 5, where I had custom urlOpener:

```js
async function urlOpener(url: string, redirectUrl: string): Promise<void> {
    console.log('custom urlOpener');
    const authSessionResult = await WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(
        url,
        redirectUrl
    );

    console.log(authSessionResult);

    if (authSessionResult.type === 'success' && Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        WebBrowser.dismissBrowser();
        await Linking.openURL(authSessionResult.url);
    }
}

const updatedConfig = {
    ...awsExports,
    oauth: {
        ...awsExports.oauth,
        urlOpener,
        redirectSignIn,
        redirectSignOut,
    },
};

Amplify.configure(updatedConfig);
```

But now it doesn't use this for some reason, I can see that because it doesn't log anything from this function and when `getCurrentUser` is executed it fails with the error `[UserUnAuthenticatedException: User needs to be authenticated to call this API.]` and when I try to log in again, it says `UserAlreadyAuthenticatedException: There is already a signed in user.` Which means it authenticated successfully but custom urlOpener was not used, so we can't access it via `getCurrentUser`

Comment: Hey Andrija, 
Did you solve this issue ? I am having the same one !